# Font awesome Icons not displaying when I access link http://fontawesome.io/icon/cog/ in my office network for IE9

Tags: font-awesome

We are accessing http://fontawesome.io/icon/cog/ in IE9 from a particular network and Icons not displaying, But icons display in crome.

We are using Font Awesome icons in a website project and they are also not displaying in IE9 in our network.

From other networks Icons are displaying properly.

Please let me know if anyone know what is the problem and if any changes do I need to do in my network.

Comment: below is the code to add css: 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Style/css/custom/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet"> version is Font Awesome 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be due to Active X permission in IE. Allow Active X to download the library.

For further reference on how to do activate it please follow [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex).

Hope this will solve your issue.

-Help :)